# How to stop my Ajax timer after one call to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js">

</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var timer, delay = 3000;
 timer = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'DeleteDatabase',
        success:
            function (response) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log("Success");
            },
        error:
            function (response) {

                console.log("failure");
            },
        });

},delay)

</script>
```

This is my code by which I am sending control to the controller. I want it to stop after one call. Should I modify this code or else please suggest your humble answers to this queries, thank you!

Comment: If you only want it to call once, why not use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)?

Comment: thank you for your help i didnt know about setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Break the loop on success:

```
        function (response) {
            //clearInterval(timer);
            console.log("Success");
            break;
        },
```

Or use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, then there won't be a loop

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code I understand that you are trying to do a ajax call after a delay, And stopping the `timer` once you get back response from the server, Else if there is any error from the server then you have to try again ..

So here is my solution.

Maintain a global variable `flag` to say if the ajax request is already made, If so then don't do consecutive requests, Then in the ajax `error` block lets remove the flag and allow the next requests for the ajax. So here is what I mean

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var timer, delay = 3000;
 var ajaxStatus = 0;             // 0 = dead, 1 = in process
 timer = setInterval(function () {
  if(ajaxStatus == 0){           // make ajax call only when its dead
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'DeleteDatabase',
        success:
            function (response) {
                clearInterval(timer); //clear the timer when the task is complete
                console.log("Success");
            },
        error:
            function (response) {
                ajaxStatus = 0    // set back status to dead so that we make another ajax request after the delay.
                console.log("failure");
            },
        });

   ajaxStatus = 1;
  }
},delay)

</script>
```